# How to stop sound from playing in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a background music and sounds in a game. There are some moments that I don't want them to execute. I use

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {    
let jump = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Jump.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
self.runAction(jump)
        }
```

for playing it, but it continue to play every time i tap the screen and I don't want it to execute when game over node already appeared, for example. 
Apple docs says that this action is not reversible. So how can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SKAction to play sound gives you no control once it starts. Instead I suggest you use AVAudioPlayer which allows you to stop playing at any time.

Comment: Thanks, but I've followed a [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78264/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-5) for that and now I have a problem. I have two sounds - for jump and for buttons. It works with jump, but when my game over background appears and I try to click my retry button it still executes jump sound too. But I clearly told it to stop playing it. And it crashes now. Shows me `signal: SIGABRT`. I need simply put `jumpSound.stop()` when I don't need it to play, right?

Comment: @Burundanga - Can't help you with the Swift code. In Obj-C you would do this: [myAudioPlayer stop];

Comment: so basically I need to stop an AudioPlayer and not a sound itself? I looked Obj-C version of swift's `stop()` and it's not what you've written, it's `-(void)stop` so I'm thinking wrong direction

Comment: @Burundanga - If you are using AVAudioPlayer to play sound then you are issuing all commands to the audio player object. Start, stop, what sound to play, volume, etc...

Comment: I figured it out. I put that sounds in a sequence and it was a bad idea I suppose. When I took them out of it they started to act normally. Thank you again!